# Get url for next and previous post from nested JSON file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I am building a markdown blog using React. I want to add the next and previous post buttons in the footer of the post page. Here is the code-

**App.tsx**-

```tsx
<Route path="/blog">
  <Route index element={<BlogPage />} />
  <Route path=":postID" element={<Postpage />} />
</Route>;
```

**city.json** file-

```json
[
    {
      "header": "Michigan ",
      "id": "MI",
      "PlaceList": [
        {
          "title": "Detroit",
          "url": "detroit"
        },
        {
          "title": "Lansing ",
          "url": "lansing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Iowa ",
      "id": "IA",
      "PlaceList": [
        {
          "title": "Ames",
          "url": "ames"
        },
        {
          "title": "Davenport ",
          "url": "davenport"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Inside the markdown folder, I have files named - detroid.md, lansing.md, ames.md. So when the postID matches with the file name it shows on the Post page. And the code of

**Postpage.tsx** is-

```tsx
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import City from './city.json';
import { PostTitle, PageHeading } from '../../components/Header';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Markdown from 'react-markdown';

const PostPage = () => {
  //Get chapter ID from URL
  const { postID } = useParams();

  // Create a flat map
  const allPosts = City.flatMap(({ header, id, PlaceList }) =>
    PlaceList.map((topics) => ({
      sectionName: header,
      sectionId: id,
      ...topics,
    })),
  );

  // Filter by url
  const filterPosts = allPosts.filter(({ url }) => url.trim() === postID);
  // console.log(allPosts);

  const folderName = filterPosts.map((post) => post.sectionId);

  //Postitle
  const pageTitle = String(filterPosts.map((post) => post.title));

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState('');

  //Get the post body
  useEffect(() => {
    import(`./${folderName}/${postID}.md`)
      .then((res) => {
        fetch(res.default)
          .then((res) => res.text())
          .then((res) => setPosts(res))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });

  const nextPage = () => setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
  const prevPage = () => setPage((prev) => prev - 1);

  //Creates the browser heading
  PageHeading(pageTitle);

  return (
    <article>
      <PostTitle pageTitle={pageTitle} />

      <Markdown>{posts}</Markdown>

      <button
        className="float-left text-teal-600"
        onClick={prevPage}
        disabled={page === 1}
      >
        Prev Page
      </button>
      <button
        className="float-right text-teal-600"
        onClick={nextPage}
        disabled={!allPosts.length}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
    </article>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

The article shows up properly, here is the example page-

[image]

**However, the previous and next buttons do not work.** I would like to get the URL of the next/previous article from the JSON file and get the post.

And if it hits the end (aka no previous or next article available) I would like them to disappear or grayed out

**Update**
For example, I am on Detroit page, and the URL is myblog.com/detroit. So, the code will import the markdown/detroit page. When I click next, I want to get postID = landing, so that the code will display markdown/lansing etc. And if it hits the end of the array, it will grayed out.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why calculate `allPosts` every time your component renders. I already explained in your previous question about how that should be done outside your component function

Comment: Also, `id` is not defined. Did you mean `ID`? I suggest you stop trying to obfuscate your code if the result becomes invalid

Comment: It's not clear how there can be _pages_ when the `ID` route parameter, when compared against the `url` properties, could not return any more than one result

Comment: Sorry, I am new to reactjs. I understand my code gets obfuscated, trying to improve. I have updated the code and replaced it with postID. I have files named after cities inside the markdown folder. So, when the postID matches with the file name it shows up. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You still haven't explained how you intend to numerically paginate through the data. Are you actually wanting to go from `/blog/detroit` to `/blog/lansing` when clicking the `next` button? If so, what is the `page` state supposed to be doing? Also, `id` is still undefined. Stop publishing faulty code and just publish **your code**

Comment: Now `Postid` is not defined. For the last time, [edit] your question with your **actual code**

Comment: I have posted my code and JSON.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple elements in the _city_ array with the same `url`? There are plenty of cities in various states with the same name (eg Springfield)

Comment: I was thinking of naming the URL like -'illinois-springfield' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is nothing here to numerically paginate so you can drop the `page` state and any related logic
2. Calculating `allPosts` each time your component renders seems wasteful. Given the JSON data is static, you can calculate it once **outside** your component function

As for the scenario you're trying to develop, you'll want to find the *index* of the matched record in order to facilitate pagination.

From there, you can produce *previous* and *next* URLs to pass to `<Link />` or `navigate()` from `react-router-dom`

```tsx
// Outside your component

const allPosts = city.flatMap(({ header, id, PlaceList }) =>
  PlaceList.map((topics) => ({
    sectionName: header,
    sectionId: id,
    ...topics,
  })),
);

const loadMarkdown = async (key: string) => {
  const resource = await import(`./${key}.md`);
  const res = await fetch(resource.default);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${resource.default}: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  return res.text();
};

interface Post {
  sectionId: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
}

interface Pagination {
  prev?: string;
  post?: Post;
  next?: string;
}
```

```tsx
const Postpage = () => {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState('');
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState<Pagination>({});

  const { postID } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // calculate prev/next page URLs
  const { prev, next, post } = useMemo<Pagination>(() => {
    const postIndex = allPosts.findIndex(({ url }) => url === postID);

    return {
      prev: allPosts[postIndex - 1]?.url,
      post: allPosts[postIndex],
      next: allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.url,
    };
  }, [postID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (post) {
      loadMarkdown(`${post.sectionId}/${post.url}`)
        .then(setMarkdown)
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  }, [post]);

  if (!post) {
    return null; // or <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  PageHeading(post.title);

  return (
    <article>
      <PostTitle pageTitle={post.title} />

      <Markdown>{markdown}</Markdown>

      <button
        className="float-left text-teal-600"
        onClick={() => navigate(prev)}
        disabled={!prev}
      >
        Prev Page
      </button>
      <button
        className="float-right text-teal-600"
        onClick={() => navigate(next)}
        disabled={!next}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
    </article>
  );
};
```

Note the dependencies passed to both the *effect* and *memo* hooks.

Comment: Thank you! I have my files in ```MI/detroit.md```. But for some reason, the 'post' is returning null.

Comment: `post` cannot possibly be `null`. It will either be the matching entry from `allPosts` or it will be `undefined`

Comment: NVM! Figured it out. It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to change the color of Prev/Next button when it cannot find any more posts?

Comment: Use CSS, eg `text-teal-600[disabled] { color: grey; }`

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly in localhost. But when I deployed it on Cloudflare pages, I got an error on the console- ```Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".``` And it is not loading. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: @aries0152 that sounds unrelated to anything in this post. Have you configured SPA routing by _not_ having a `404.html` file? See https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/configuration/serving-pages/#single-page-application-spa-rendering