# Use JSON file as Pagination in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, next.js

I am building a science blog in which the URLs of the posts are stored in a static JSON file.

`ScienteTopics.json-`

```
[
  {
    "Subject": "Mathematics",
    "chapters": "mathematics",
    "contentList": [
      {
        "content": "Algebra",
        "url": "algebra-content-url"
      },
      {
        "content": "Trigonometry",
        "url": "trigonometry-content-url"
      },
      {
        "content": "Geometry",
        "url": "geometry-content-url"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Physics",
    "chapters": "physics",
    "contentList": [
      {
        "content": "Newton's 1st law",
        "url": "newtons-fisrt-law-url"
      },
      {
        "content": "Newton's 2nd law",
        "url": "newtons-second-law-url"
      },
      {
        "content": "Newton's 3rd law ",
        "url": "newtons-third-law-url"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to add pagination on a single post page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77749867/2248721) works perfectly for ReactJS but the only problem is `useEffect` hook uses 'client' which conflicts with the `generateStaticParams()` of NextJS. I have modified the code -

**Code update 2**
`page.tsx-`

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import fs from "fs"

import Link from "next/link"
import Markdown from "react-markdown"
import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex"
import remarkMath from "remark-math"
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw"
import matter from "gray-matter"
import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'

import ScienceTopics from '@/app/(subjects)/scienceBlog/ScienteTopics.json'
import path from "path"
import { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next"



const allPosts = ScienceTopics.flatMap(({ Subject, chapters, contentList }) =>
contentList.map((topics) => ({

    subjectName: Subject,
    subjectId: chapters,
    ...topics,

  })),
);


const folder = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/ScienceTopics');// put it outside of app folder



// generates static pages 
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return allPosts.map((post) => ({
    chapterID: post.subjectId,
    postID: post.url

  }))
}


interface Post {
  subjectId: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
}

interface Pagination {
  prev: string | null;
  next: string | null;
  post: Post | null;
  switchSubject: boolean;
}

const ScienceBlogPage = ({params}:{params:any) => {
  
  
  //gets ids from URL
  
  const postID = params.postID;
  // calculate prev/next page URLs and switch subjects
  const { prev, next, post, switchSubject } = useMemo<Pagination>(() => {
    const postIndex = allPosts.findIndex(({ url }) => url === postID);

    if (postIndex === -1) {
    return {
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      post: null,
      switchSubject: false
    };
  }

    const currentPost = allPosts[postIndex];
    const isLastPostInSubject =
      postIndex === allPosts.length - 1 ||
      allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId !== currentPost.subjectId;

    return {
       prev: allPosts[postIndex - 1]?.url || null,
       post: currentPost,
       next: isLastPostInSubject ? null : allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.url || null,
       switchSubject: isLastPostInSubject
  };
  }, [postID]);



  if(!post) {
    return null;
  }
  const curr_post = GetPostContent(`${folder}`,`${post.subjectId}`,`${post.url}`)
  return (

    <>

      <h1>{curr_post.title}</h1>
      <hr className="my-6 border border-dashed bg-sky-600 h-0.5" />
      <article lang="bn" className="prose lg:prose-xl">
        <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]} rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex, rehypeRaw]}>
          {curr_post.content}</Markdown>
      
      </article>
     <Link
        className="float-left text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!prev}
        href={prev ? `/${post.subjectId}/${prev}` : ''}
      >
        prev
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="float-right text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!next}
        href={next ? `/${post.subjectId}/${next}` : ''}
      >
        next
      </Link>
      {switchSubject && (
        <div>
          {/* Render something to indicate that you are switching to the next subject */}
          Switching to the next subject: {allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId}
        </div>
      )}
    </>

  )
}

export default ScienceBlogPage
```

Though the `${post. url}` updates properly, `${post.subjectId}` does not update also the link tries to go to 'url/undefined' when it hits the end.

How can I update the value of `${post.subjectId}` when it hits the end of the 'contentList array' on JSON? For example, when it finishes showing all the content under Mathematics, the value will change to Physics, and so on.

And how do I make the Link disabled when there's no more item in Subject in JSON using NextJS?

**Update 1:**
The updated code based on Saloni Sikdar's response gives me the following error. Any idea how to resolve it?

```
Argument of type '() => { prev?: undefined; post?: undefined; next?: undefined; switchSubject?: undefined; } | { prev: string; post: { title: string; url: string; subjectName: string; subjectId: string; }; next: string | null; switchSubject: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Pagination'.
  Type '{ prev?: undefined; post?: undefined; next?: undefined; switchSubject?: undefined; } | { prev: string; post: { title: string; url: string; subjectName: string; subjectId: string; }; next: string | null; switchSubject: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Pagination'.
    Type '{ prev: string; post: { title: string; URL: string; subjectName: string; subjectId: string; }; next: string | null; switchSubject: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Pagination'.
      Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

And another error from the updated code on the bottom where the link is declared-

```
Cannot find the name 'postIndex'. Did you mean 'postID'?ts(2552)
page.tsx(106, 9): 'postID' is declared here
```

**Update 2**

From the discussion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54496398/2248721) I was able to fix the error of update 1 and I have updated the code on the original post. Now it is not going to `url/undefined` but the `${post.subjectId}` is still not updating. It only loops inside the array.

Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue of `${post.subjectId}` not updating and the link trying to go to `'url/undefined'`, you need to handle the transition between different subjects. When the `postIndex` reaches the end of the current subject's `contentList`, you should switch to the next subject.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
const ScienceBlogPage = ({ params }: { params: any }) => {
  // gets ids from url
  const postID = params.postID;

  // calculate prev/next page URLs and switch subjects
  const { prev, next, post, switchSubject } = useMemo<Pagination>(() => {
    const postIndex = allPosts.findIndex(({ url }) => url === postID);

    if (postIndex === -1) {
      return {};
    }

    const currentPost = allPosts[postIndex];
    const isLastPostInSubject =
      postIndex === allPosts.length - 1 ||
      allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId !== currentPost.subjectId;

    return {
      prev: allPosts[postIndex - 1]?.url,
      post: currentPost,
      next: isLastPostInSubject ? null : allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.url,
      switchSubject: isLastPostInSubject,
    };
  }, [postID]);

  if (!post) {
    return null;
  }

  const curr_post = getPostContent(`${post.subjectId}`, `${post.url}`);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{curr_post.title}</h1>
      <hr className="my-6 border border-dashed bg-sky-600 h-0.5" />
      <article lang="bn" className="prose lg:prose-xl">
        <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]} rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex, rehypeRaw]}>
          {curr_post.content}
        </Markdown>
      </article>
      <Link
        className="float-left text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!prev}
        href={prev ? `/${post.subjectId}/${prev}` : ''}
      >
        prev
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="float-right text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!next}
        href={next ? `/${post.subjectId}/${next}` : ''}
      >
        next
      </Link>
      {switchSubject && (
        <div>
          {/* Render something to indicate that you're switching to the next subject */}
          Switching to the next subject: {allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

In this modified code, the `switchSubject` variable is used to determine if the next post is in a different subject. If so, you can render something to indicate that you're switching to the next subject. Additionally, the `href` for the next and prev links is updated to include the `subjectId`. This should prevent the link from trying to go to `'url/undefined'`.

**Update**

It seems like the issue might be related to the closure capturing of the `postIndex` variable inside the `useMemo` callback. Since the `useMemo` callback is executed only once during the component's initialization, the captured value of `postIndex` won't be updated when the component re-renders.

To fix this issue, you can move the calculation of `postIndex` outside the `useMemo` callback and use it directly within the callback. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
const ScienceBlogPage = ({ params }: { params: any }) => {
  // gets ids from url
  const postID = params.postID;

  // calculate prev/next page URLs and switch subjects
  const postIndex = allPosts.findIndex(({ url }) => url === postID);

  const { prev, next, post, switchSubject } = useMemo<Pagination>(() => {
    if (postIndex === -1) {
      return {};
    }

    const currentPost = allPosts[postIndex];
    const isLastPostInSubject =
      postIndex === allPosts.length - 1 ||
      allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId !== currentPost.subjectId;

    return {
      prev: allPosts[postIndex - 1]?.url,
      post: currentPost,
      next: isLastPostInSubject ? null : allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.url,
      switchSubject: isLastPostInSubject,
    };
  }, [postID, postIndex]);

  if (!post) {
    return null;
  }

  const curr_post = getPostContent(`${post.subjectId}`, `${post.url}`);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{curr_post.title}</h1>
      <hr className="my-6 border border-dashed bg-sky-600 h-0.5" />
      <article lang="bn" className="prose lg:prose-xl">
        <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]} rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex, rehypeRaw]}>
          {curr_post.content}
        </Markdown>
      </article>
      <Link
        className="float-left text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!prev}
        href={prev ? `/${post.subjectId}/${prev}` : ''}
      >
        prev
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="float-right text-teal-600"
        aria-disabled={!next}
        href={next ? `/${post.subjectId}/${next}` : ''}
      >
        next
      </Link>
      {switchSubject && (
        <div>
          {/* Render something to indicate that you're switching to the next subject */}
          Switching to the next subject: {allPosts[postIndex + 1]?.subjectId}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

This should ensure that the `postIndex` value is updated on each render, and you won't encounter the issue of it getting stuck in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am getting an error with your code. Can you look at it please?

Comment: I have updated my post based on your response with the error I am having.

Comment: @aries0152 , updated the answer above. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. However, when it hits the end of the list, say ``mathematics/geometry-content-url``, if I click next it does not go to ``physics/newtons-fisrt-law-url``.